# Fastest way of writing the first 10 000 lines of data file to new file

Tags: java

I want the first ten thousand lines of a hyuuge (.csv) file.

The naive way of

1) creating a reader & writer

2) reading the original file line for line

3) writing the first ten thousand lines to a new file

can't be the fastest, can it?

This will be a common operation in my app so I'm slightly concerned about speed, but also just curious.

Thanks.

Comment: The *fastest* way *is* to read stream using `BufferedReader` and append `strings` via `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @AVD: I guess you meant `StringBuilder`; `StringBuffer` is synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing *fast* I/O in Java but without benchmarking for your particular case, it's kind of difficult to shoot out a figure/advice. Here are a few ways you can try benchmarking:

- Buffered reader/writers with maybe varying buffer sizes
- Reading the entire file in memory (if it can be) and doing an in-memory split and writing it all in a single go
- Using NIO file API for reading/writing files (look into Channels)

Comment: Ah, so this is not a question with a hard and fast answer- hope it is still SO appropriate. Upvote, but waiting at least 24 hours to accept.

Comment: @The Unfun Cat: Unfortunately yes. Plus, due to the line oriented nature of your data (i.e. text data as opposed to binary), using advanced file I/O optimizations might be a bit difficult to apply given that they rely on reading fixed size of data (buffer size) from the underlying source.

Comment: +1 if you have a HDD, the limitation can be how fast you can read the file from disk, so it doesn't matter what you do.  If you are reading from SSD or disk cache, then you can see a relative improvement by using other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to read/write 10,000 lines or so:

- it will probably take longer to start up a new JVM than to read / write the file,
- the read / write time should be a fraction of a second ... doing it the naive way, and
- the overall speed up from a copying algorithm is unlikely to be worthwhile.

Having said that, you can do better than reading a line at a time using `BufferedReader.readLine()` or whatever.

- Depending on the character encoding of the file, you will get better performance by doing byte-wise I/O with a BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream with large buffer sizes.  Just write a loop to read a byte, conditionally update the line counter and write the byte ... until you have copied the requisite number of lines. (This assumes that you can detect the CR and/or LF characters by examining the bytes.  This is true for all  character encodings I know about.)
- If you use NIO and ByteBuffers, you can further reduce the amount of in-memory copying, though the CR / LF counting logic will be more complicated.

But the first question you should ask is whether it is even worthwhile bothering to optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

Are the lines the same length. If so you can use RandomAccessFile to read x bytes and then write those bytes to a new file. It may be quite memory intensive though. I suspect this would be quicker but probably worth benchmarking. This solution would only work for fixed length lines